# SQLAlchemy: Distinct inside group by

Tags: python, postgresql, group-by, sqlalchemy, distinct

I would like to use distinct inside a group_by query, e.g.:

```
session.query(Product.attribute_x, func.min(Product.price), distinct(Product.color)). group_by(Product.attribute_x)
```

That is, for each value of attribute_x, I want to find the lowest price and all of the colors available.

I don't seem to be able to use distinct in this way in SQLAlchemy. Can anyone please suggest an efficient method of identifying the distinct colors for each value of attribute_x (without creating a new query for each value of attribute_x)?

I'm using SQLALchemy 1.3.4 on PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`array_agg`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.array_agg):

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import array_agg

session.query(Product.attribute_x,
              func.min(Product.price),
              array_agg(distinct(Product.color))).\
    group_by(Product.attribute_x)
```

In this case `func.array_agg()` would work as well. The Postgresql dialect specific form just ensures that the return type is understood as a Postgresql `ARRAY` instead of the generic one, in case you want to use any of the array operators etc.